# Does Alter table commits Transaction in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transactions

I want to use alter table statement in transaction. I just want to confirm whether alter statement commits the transaction. If so, I want to avoid this commit so that if statement4 fails I can roll back statement1 also. Any suggestion.

My code is like:

```
Begin transaction
    statement 1
    statement 2
    ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER tr_name
    statement 3
    statement 4
Commit transaction.
```

Comment: If you're doing SQL Server development, you really *ought* to have an instance you can mess about on (The Express edition is free, so cost shouldn't be an issue). You could have run an experiment with this yourself in less time than it takes to ask the question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Actually I don't have sql server with me right now and I have to give the answer. That's why I asked it. Other wise I would have executed it.

Answer (score 0):

before you start transaction .

add SET XACT_ABORT ON;

Like

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
Begin transaction
  your transation content
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```